# Static vs non-static variable C++

Tags: c++, static-variables

```
class Expression
{
    private:
       ToStringDisplay* toString;
    public:
        ......
};

   // Some code
   if (toString == NULL)
   // do something
```

When I debugged, toString referred to an address, not NULL.
But if I declared `static ToStringDisplay* toString;` to instead,  toString referred to NULL ?
What differ between them ?

Comment: This question, posed in this way, is way too ambiguous/incomplete.

Comment: can you show code where you assign toString?

Comment: You are aware there are no classes in C, right?

Comment: @ddriver you realize this is C++ right?

Comment: @btevfik - check the previous revision of the question.

Answer (score 2):

as a standard in C/C++, static variables are always initialized to null if not stated otherwise. However, for nonstatic local variables there is no such a guarantee

Comment: Are you sure that static variables are initialized to NULL in C. e.g. static int arr[5]; //arr will just be 5*sizeof(int) Bytes of allocated data containing whatever happened to be there previously. I'm only doubting that it is NOT initialized to null because I know that static variable are stored in a different section of memory than the stack and the heap. --- C++ definitely does initialize to null though.

Comment: If static variable was not intialized, it would be contained in BSS Segment.
See more at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment
So I think it would be initialized to zero

Answer (score 1):

Static member variables are initialized to zero according to http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/811-static-member-variables/ where all other are undefined, unless you initialize them explicitly, so they will have whatever random value that was in memory before. For an explanation on what's the difference with static and non-static see the above link.